# Kendo UI Window Relative to Button Position

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-window

I'm trying to bring Kendo UI Modal Window right next to my button and it not working.

Here is my button click code:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var x = $("#button").offset().left;
    var y = $("#button").offset().top;

    window1 = $('#window1');
    if (!window1.data("kendoWindow")) {
        window1.kendoWindow({
            actions: ["Refresh", "Close"],
            width: "450px",
            position: {
                left: x,
                top: y
            },
            title: "Window Title",
            modal: true,
            resizable: false
        });
    }
    window1.show();
    window1.data("kendoWindow").open();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

All set.

```
    $("#window1").closest(".k-window").css({
        top: y,
        left: x
    });
```